# Facing issue while installing any thing in angular file through npm

Tags: angularjs, npm-install

Facing issue while installing any thing in angular project through npm.... this time uploading the screenshot while installing jquery/ updating jquery. may be the issue with moment js.

Facing issue while installing anything in npm (angular project)

Comment: Plz don't upload a screenshot but rather copy the relevant parts of your cmd output. Also include all required info s.t. somemone else understands your question,  e.g. why do you think this issue is related to moment.js

Comment: What issue are you facing? Do you have a specific error message or description of the problematic behavior? Share a [mcve] (package.json, environment details, commands you've run, etc) as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.